# Is there a way to deploy a servlet on glassfish without showing it on a web browser?

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I m a beginner in develeping java ee applications. I have made a servlet which has no html content to show. I want it just to get deployed without opening in a browser.

here is my servlet class --

```
public class xmltosql extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        System.out.println("this is in current data");
        try
        {
          // instream receives string from server 1  
          InputStream in = req.getInputStream();


      // testing code
          DocumentBuilderFactory factory = null;
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    Document ret = null;

    try {
      factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // creating xml document ret using instream data
        ret = builder.parse(in);
        System.out.println("ret : "+ret);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {   
        // establishing jdbc connection to database on server 2
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nic", "root", "jumanjis");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        // initiating a queue to recieve object
        Queue<data> q = new LinkedList<data>();     
        if(req!=null){
            // initiating object of data class which takes row values of table on server 1
             data obj = new data();
             // reading xml string from inputstream
            NodeList employeelist = ret.getElementsByTagName("employee");
            for(int i=0; i<employeelist.getLength();i++){
                Node n = employeelist.item(i);
                if(n.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element employee = (Element) n;
                    NodeList childnodes = employee.getChildNodes();

                        for(int j=0;j<childnodes.getLength();j++){
                            Node child = childnodes.item(j);
                                if(child.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                                    Element x = (Element) child;

                                        // initializing members of data class object
                                        switch (x.getTagName()) {
                                            case "id":
                                                obj.id = Integer.parseInt(x.getTextContent());
                                                break;
                                            case "name":
                                                obj.name = x.getTextContent();
                                                break;
                                            case "age":
                                                obj.age = Integer.parseInt(x.getTextContent());
                                                break;
                                            case "city":
                                                obj.city = x.getTextContent();
                                                break;
                                            case "country":
                                                obj.country = x.getTextContent();
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                break;
                                        }   
                                 }
                        }
                }
            }
            // inserting object of data class to queue
            q.add(obj);
                // iterating through the objects in the queue
               Iterator iterator = q.iterator();
               while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    data first =q.remove();
                    // updating the table xyz on server 2 using the object in queue
                    st.executeUpdate("insert into xyz values("+first.id+", '"+first.name+"', "+first.age+", '"+first.city+"', '"+first.country+"')");
                        }       
            ret = null;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    // storing data in db


}
catch (IOException e) 
{
System.err.println(e); 
e.printStackTrace();
}

    }
}
```

below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>xmltosql</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>xmltosql</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>xmltosql</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I just want this servlet to work in the background without being called on a web browser.

Comment: The company where I am interning have specifically asked me to do it on servlet.

Comment: I want it to keep running and receiving xml from another java application(not webapp). That java app sends an xml at a scheduled time. That all is working properly I tested it. But when I deploy my servlet it opens up a browser showing a message "HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL". Now even if I close the browser manualIy, the servlet keeps receving xml from that java app. I m just looking for a solution to not activate the browser in the starting.

Comment: Oh? Your actual problem is thus with the tooling (e.g. the IDE) not with the servlet? The described behavior is not related to servlets. It's specific to the IDE. By default, starting a server and deploying a webapp should not magically spawn a webbrowser instance on server machine at all. Perhaps you did rightclick servlet and then "run on server" on your development environment or so like a beginner would do. The normal procedure, however, is to deploy project to server and then start the server.

Comment: Oh now I get it. It's working now. Thanks for your help. :)